# Multiple Regions in Customer Registration Form

Tags: customer, forms, ce-1.4.0.1

We need to add a US/Canada `<option>` element before `region_id` to select US or Canada in the Registration Form, and change the `region_id` `<option>` element based on if the user selects either using javascript. Here is the current template, which looks similar to the magento default:

```
<div class="input-box">
    <label for="region_id"><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
       <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $('region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  "<?php echo $this->getFormData()->getRegionId() ?>");
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text" style="display:none;" />
</div>
```

In the Admin panel under `System -> Configuration -> General`, Countries allowed are `United States` and `Canada`. If I can pull these both separately into a javascript array then switching them will be much easier. How can I accomplish this?

**Edit:** Just had an idea for this, is it possible to detect if the visitor is in US/Canada based on `$_SERVER` environment variables to auto select a region to populate State/Providence once and not involve javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is mod_geoip2 for apache to get the location from the ip:

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/mod_geoip2

Comment: Very nice. I just need to figure out how  to pass this through the form and get the options array.

Comment: You can add a shipping-address to the order, then I think it should be set automatically

Answer (score 1):

Here is my extension which allows GeoIP integration on Magento level

https://github.com/tim-bezhashvyly/geoip